# What was the price of going from England to New England as a passenger in the 1600s?

Tags: england, 17th-century, colonial-america

Lots of places mention that traveling to New England was so expensive that many people became indentured servants to get across, but I couldn't find a place that actually says how expensive it was.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that the Massachusetts Bay company [had a rule](http://teachersinstitute.yale.edu/curriculum/units/2003/2/03.02.08.x.html) setting out some costs and the limits on the number of passengers that ships could carry.

- A ship of two hundred tons should not carry more than one hundred
  passengers (other ships adhered to the same proportions).
- The cost of passage was 5 pounds sterling for an adult (and 4 pounds
  for a ton of goods).

---

An [alternative source](http://craigwhitmoreparker.wixsite.com/bissell-history/settlers-of-northampton) claims that the passage costs during the "[Great (Puritan) Migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puritan_migration_to_New_England_(1620%E2%80%9340))" (1620 – 1640) were

- 5 pounds sterling for an adult
- Children over the age of 12 were carried at half cost (2 pounds and
  10 shillings)
- Children under 12 were carried free of charge
- 10 pounds sterling for a horse
- 3 pounds per ton of freight

---

It seems that this cost of passage for an adult is also comparable with the [cost of passage](https://www.csmonitor.com/2004/1116/p18s02-hfks.html) of 5 pounds for an adult on the Mayflower in 1620.

---

Comparing the values of money in the past with modern values is fraught with difficulties. The [Measuring Worth](https://www.measuringworth.com/) site has a simple-to-use [calculator](https://www.measuringworth.com/calculators/ukcompare/index.php) that computes the modern equivalent of past monetary amounts, using five different measures, that can often help gain some insight into the true "cost" of something in the past.

Comment: Using the calculator above, it appears that 5 pounds can be considered to be equivalent to anything between 956.6 pounds and 262,100.00 pounds, depending on what you're using the 5 pounds for. I tend to like the view that the 5 pounds should be measured as income value, and therefore equates to about £23,700 today.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate measurement is how you could have paid as an indentured servant. 3 to 5 years of your life. Maybe comparable with a 5 to 10 years mortgage?